# Get id row with MAX and MIN time in day from a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I don't have any idea how i can get this information.

This is my query

```
SELECT
    CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) AS report_date,
    MIN(CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) AS work_start, <--- I want to get id of this row
    MAX(CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) AS work_end    <--- and this
FROM       reports
WHERE      reports.report_creation_datetime >= '2016-02-01'
AND        reports.report_creation_datetime < LAST_DAY('2016-02-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY   CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS DATE)
```

---

SAMPLE DATA

```
---reports table
report_id     report_creation_datetime
 ------------------------------------
   82           2016-02-01 07:20:00
   80           2016-02-01 10:30:00
   85           2016-02-01 17:00:00
   88           2016-02-02 08:00:00
   87           2016-02-02 16:00:00
   81           2016-02-03 10:50:00
```

I want to get

```
---expected result
report_date      work_start      wstart_id     ...
 -------------------------------------------------------
 2016-02-01       07:20:00          82         ...
 2016-02-02       08:00:00          88         ...
 2016-02-03       10:50:00          81         ...
 ...
 2016-02-29       07:30:00          199        ...
```

I think about subquery like this 
WHERE date = MIN(date)
but it is not correct

Comment: What error are you having?  Also it would be helpful if you could provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't have any error but I don't know how i can get id of row which I called as work_start and work_end

Comment: So you want the row holding the groupwise minimum Report_creation_date timevalue for each day ?

Comment: id of row which holding minimum and id of row with maximum date for every day in month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to do this.  You can `join` the table back to itself using `aggregation` in both subqueries.  You could use `user-defined variables`.

Perhaps the easiest solution is 2 correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
    CAST(r.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) AS report_date,
    MIN(CAST(r.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) AS work_start,
    (SELECT id FROM reports r2 
    WHERE CAST(r.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) = CAST(r2.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) 
    ORDER BY r2.report_creation_datetime 
    LIMIT 1) work_start_id,
    MAX(CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) AS work_end,
    (SELECT id FROM reports r3 
    WHERE CAST(r.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) = CAST(r3.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) 
    ORDER BY r3.report_creation_datetime DESC
    LIMIT 1) work_end_id
FROM       reports r
WHERE      r.report_creation_datetime >= '2016-02-01'
AND        r.report_creation_datetime < LAST_DAY('2016-02-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY   CAST(r.report_creation_datetime AS DATE)
```

---

Here's an alternative which should return ties as well:

```
SELECT t.report_date, t.work_start, t.work_end, r1.id minid, r2.id maxid 
FROM (
    SELECT
        CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) AS report_date,
        MIN(CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) AS work_start,
        MAX(CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) AS work_end
    FROM       reports
    WHERE      reports.report_creation_datetime >= '2016-02-01'
    AND        reports.report_creation_datetime < LAST_DAY('2016-02-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY   CAST(reports.report_creation_datetime AS DATE)
) t 
    JOIN reports r1 ON t.report_date = CAST(r1.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) AND t.work_start = CAST(r1.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)
    JOIN reports r2 ON t.report_date = CAST(r2.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) AND t.work_end = CAST(r2.report_creation_datetime AS TIME)
```

Comment: There's far too much query here

Comment: @Strawberry -- OP wants min(time) and corresponding id and max(time) and corresponding id for each possible day.  Care to post a solution easier?  I see 3 possible options; I provided what I thought was the easiest.

Comment: This query works correctly but when I have two reports in one day with this same datetime, attribute work_start and work_end will have this same id. Is easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Karpol -- if ties are a concern (somewhat a different question), then you can't use the correlated subquery approach.  Instead you need to `join` the table to itself multiple times.  The first join is to get the max and the second is to get the min.  It's not pretty -- basically take what I have in the correlated subqueries, modify slightly, and move to joins.  This will make the ties show up.

Comment: @Karpol -- Updated the answer with the `join` approach which should include ties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to achieve something like this? (not tested)

```
SELECT distinct CAST(mainReports.report_creation_datetime AS DATE) AS 
report_date, workStartReports.id as StartId, workEndReports.id as EndId FROM
(SELECT MIN(CAST(report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) as minDate,
MAX(CAST(report_creation_datetime AS TIME)) as maxDate From reports WHERE
report_creation_datetime >= '2016-02-01' AND report_creation_datetime < 
LAST_DAY('2016-02-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY) as MinMaxDates, reports as 
mainReports, reports as workStartReports, reports as workEndReports WHERE
 mainReports.report_creation_datetime >= '2016-02-01' AND 
mainReports.report_creation_datetime < LAST_DAY('2016-02-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND workStartReports.report_creation_datetime = MinMaxDates.minDate AND 
workEndReports.report_creation_datetime = MinMaxDates.maxDate
```

Comment: This query return #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: but i did not even use any group by, are you sure you are exactly using the query i posted?

Comment: @AshrafIqbal -- that error is coming from your invalid use of aggregation in the joins...

Comment: This query return zero results.

Comment: not for me, I tested for a sample database table, are you sure you have data in your table for the date range? (feb 1st)?